# JavaFX - Playing loop video

Tags: loops, video, javafx

How should I loop a video in JavaFX?
I'm trying to just play a video one time after another, so I was looking for some sample code in many places and I could'nt make it work!

This is what doesn't work for me:

```
public MyMediaPlayer (){
    media = new Media(getVideo());
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    startMediaPlayer();
}

private String getVideo() {
    return getClass().getResource("videos/limbo.mp4").toString();
}

public final void startMediaPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer.setMute(true);
    mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE); //this is the line that should do the magic, but it doesn't...
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Comment: I found the problem, but no the solution: The thing is that I have an StackPane that contains the MyMediaPlayer and a BorderPane with all the UI. But when the video ends, the StackPane doesn't update, so it freezes in the last frame of the video. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (video loops forever).  I can't replicate your issue.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VideoPlayerExample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final MediaPlayer oracleVid = new MediaPlayer(
      new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv")
    );
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new MediaView(oracleVid)), 540, 208));
    stage.show();

    oracleVid.setMute(true);
    oracleVid.setRate(20);

    oracleVid.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

    oracleVid.play();
  }
}
```

> I'm under Java 7, doesn't work there . . . the problem seems to be MP4 format.

If you can't play MP4 files, either:

1. The MP4 is not encoded in a format JavaFX understands (the [JavaFX 2.2 Media javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) details the allowed formats).

   OR
2. You don't have appropriate codecs installed on your machine to allow the MP4 file to be decoded.  See the [JavaFX 2.2 Media system requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2-5/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2-5.htm#A1112979) for information on what you need to install on your machine to allow MP4 files to be displayed.

Comment: And if I don't want to create the VideoPlayer as my main application? If I just want it to be used as a background? How'd you share the video outside the class you wrote?

Comment: Sample works for me Win7, Java8b112.  Your other questions in comments I do not understand but they don't seem related to the title of the question, so ask them in a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm under Java 7, doesn't work there, but with respect to main question, the problem seems to be MP4 format. All my work runs perfectly now working with FLV format instead. Thanks, jewel!

Comment: Updated answer to include information on playing MP4 files in JavaFX.