# How to play all the video in a folder?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm trying to play all the videos inside a specific folder.
I've already build the code for play a single file and it works.
I want to be able to play all the videos inside a folder ordered by the name, and when the list is finished I want to restart from the begin.
How can I do?
This is my starting code:

```
public class Activity_Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    String SrcPath = "/sdcard/B-Happy/b-happy.mp4";
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: see if this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597460/javafx-playing-loop-video

Comment: 1) get the list of files in your desired dir. 2) sort them by file name. 3) play 1st. 4) in `OnCompletionListener` start playing next. 5) if you have reached the last - start from first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the File instance of the directory:

```
File dir = new File("Path");
```

To get the complete path this may help:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
```

You can get the files using:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Note: Those files can be directories. Just check file.isDirectory();

Edit: Sorting should be pretty easy. Just add all files to an ArrayList and call:

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return f1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(f2.getName());
    }
});
```